# can anti-virus software detect virus which had been compressed into multiple files?

Tags: security, virus, anti-virus, virus-removal

can anti-virus software detect virus which had been compressed into multiple files? I think the answer is no although not sure since I don't know how anti-virus software works.

Comment: Depends if the security software can scan compress files or not.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the antivirus.  You can use the [EICAR test](http://www.eicar.org/86-0-Intended-use.html) which works with ***most*** antivirus programs to check how many levels of archive yours checks.

Most at least check the first level archive, but it may depend on an option in the antivirus.

Comment: Can most anti-virus software decompress files separated into different compressed files? Like a file that was compressed and separated into (1.zip.001, 1.zip.002, 1.zip).

Comment: Oh, that I've never tried, but if you really want to know do the test I mentioned.  Place the EICAR test in a file in such an archive and see if it detects it.